# 2016 Chevy Malibu start up problems

Tags: engine, battery

I have a 2016 chevy Malibu with about 84,000 miles. I just bought this car from the dealership barely 2 months ago. My first issue started one morning I went out to start it and all the lights and radio came on but all it did was click I had to jump it. Second issue happened I was in a drive threw and as soon as the car went into auto stop the engine wouldn't start back up. All the lights and radio remained on but once again when I tried restarting its clicked and had to get another jump. 2 weeks later and I went out to start the car and it was completely dead no lights no click. Jumped it again and it worked. Not even 2 hours later I went back out to go to the store and all the lights and radio came on but once again only clicked. Calling the shop Monday but wanted to see if anyone had any ideas what's going on.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! While it should be good for about 5 years, it sure sounds like your battery is no longer providing the power the car needs to get it started. I'd have the mechanic look at this first.

Comment: Your alternator isn't keeping the battery charged....

Comment: I would second Paulster2 : have the battery properly checked to start with.

Comment: Well turns out the battery was bad and the battery that was in my car specifically said do not use on vehicles with the start stop feature which my car has. Who ever put that battery in there before I bought it I guess didn't pay attention just glad I got it figured out before something else went wrong! Thank you guys for the help!